# Передача данных между electron.js и python

Tags: python, electron

Встал важный вопрос в написании приложения на electron. Как же связать какой-то код например на python, где работает код и собирает информацию с датчиков. Каких то системных служб и тд
и передавать его в процессы electron.

Я слышал о ptyhon shell.  И так же слышал что он возвращает данные После завершения процесса.
Не уверен, что на все 100 понял как именно. Но такое мне не подходит.

Есть ещё 1 вопрос который так же важен.
После билда проекта на electron мы получаем .exe и вагон файлов к нему.
я не уверен, что файлы того же python и библиотек на нём будут собраны в тот же пакет.
тут нужен сторонний сборщик ?

Comment: Общайся по хттп.

Comment: Eri,
 можно документацию какую. Не представляю как это будет работать